# call matlab dll from c++: fail to initialize the library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, matlab, sift, matlab-compiler

I try to use Demo code for detecting and matching SIFT features of David Lowe (lowe@cs.ubc.ca)

in my code. So I compile the (.m)file in Matlab to generate DLL. Here is the command code in Matlab:

```
           mcc -B csharedlib:SiftMatch match.m sift.m -v
```

However, when I use the DLL in my C++ code( under VS2010), there is a problem:

```
              SiftMatchInitialize();
   This function returned false. I could not initialize the library.
```

and debug showed that:

```
    bool MW_CALL_CONV SiftMatchInitializeWithHandlers(
    mclOutputHandlerFcn error_handler,
    mclOutputHandlerFcn print_handler)
{
    int bResult = 0;
  if (_mcr_inst != NULL)
    return true;
  if (!mclmcrInitialize())
    return false;
  if (!GetModuleFileName(GetModuleHandle("SiftMatch"), path_to_dll, _MAX_PATH))
    return false;
    {
        mclCtfStream ctfStream = 
            mclGetEmbeddedCtfStream(path_to_dll);
        if (ctfStream) {
            bResult = mclInitializeComponentInstanceEmbedded(   &_mcr_inst,
                                                                error_handler, 
                                                                print_handler,
                                                                ctfStream);
            mclDestroyStream(ctfStream);
        } else {
            bResult = 0;
        }
    }  
    if (!bResult)
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

In this function ctfStream is NULL and bResult equals 0.
So, what's the problem?

Comment: can you try the same, but with a default shared library project (ie just ass sift.m, do not change any parameters) instead of invoking mcc directly? If that works ok, compare the project output with your mcc line: the clue will be in the different options.

Comment: Thanks. I tried  using the Project Interface. And I found that there were some errors in the .m file when build. So maybe that's the reason why it fails the initialization.

Comment: @lucky if you are using C++, why don't use opencv? it has SIFT implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Do not include the .c/.cpp files generated by MATLAB Compiler into your project. Only the header file and .lib file is needed.